# How to create Lamba function in Java confusion

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors

I have an interface called `GridComponent`:

```
package lms.grid;

/**
 * An interface for components that can be encoded as strings and placed in a grid.
 *
 * @provided
 */
public interface GridComponent {

    /**
     * Returns an encoding of this component as a string.
     *
     * @return the encoding of this component as a string.
     */
    String getEncoding();
}
```

and I have a class called GameGrid and please scroll to the generate method, you can see that it uses a lambda function to put "ERROR" into the grid at every coordinate. Like I want to do the same thing but with 'o' and 'w', I want to insert a lambda into the grid that returns the appropriate character code "o" and "w"

```
package lms.grid;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * The GameGrid is responsible for managing the state and initialisation of the game's grid.
 * It provides the Map structure to hold the coordinates of each node in the grid. It also
 * maintains the size of the grid using a range variable. The range value donates how many
 * nodes each hexagonal grid node extends to.
 *
 * <p>
 * Summary: Initializes a grid of the game.
 *
 */
public class GameGrid {
    /** The grid of the game */
    private Map<Coordinate, GridComponent> grid;
    /** The range of the grid. */
    private int range;

    /**
     * Create a new GameGrid with the given range, stored in a Map.
     * A private helper method, generate() has been provided to assist you with the logic of the hexagonal coordinate system.
     *
     * @param range The range of the grid.
     * @requires range > 0
     */
    public GameGrid(int range) {
        if (range <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range must be greater than 0");
        }
        this.range = range;
        this.grid = generate(range);
    }

    /**
     * Get a copy of the grid of the game.
     *
     * @return A copy of the grid of the game.
     */
    public Map<Coordinate, GridComponent> getGrid() {
        return new HashMap<>(this.grid);
    }

    /**
     * Get the range of the grid.
     *
     * @return The range of the grid.
     */
    public int getRange() {
        return this.range;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method:
     * Generates a grid with the given range, starting from the origin (the centre) and maintaining a
     * balanced shape for the entire mapping structure.
     * This has been provided to support you with the hexagonal coordinate logic.
     * @param range The range of the map.
     * @provided
     */
    private Map<Coordinate, GridComponent> generate(int range) {
        Map<Coordinate, GridComponent> tempGrid = new HashMap<>();
        for (int q = -range; q <= range; q++) { // From negative to positive (inclusive)
            for (int r = -range; r <= range; r++) { // From negative to positive (inclusive)
                for (int s = -range; s <= range; s++) { // From negative to positive (inclusive)
                    if (q + r + s == 0) {
                        // Useful to default to error
                        tempGrid.put(new Coordinate(q, r, s), () -> "ERROR");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tempGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Set the GridComponent at the given coordinate.
     *
     * @param coordinate The coordinate of the GridComponent.
     * @param component  The GridComponent to be set.
     */
    public void setCoordinate(Coordinate coordinate, GridComponent component) {
        this.grid.put(coordinate, component);
    }
}
```

The encoding is just a letter like "o" or "w"

For my project I am analyzing and parsing data from a txt file. My file contains 'o' and 'w'.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
GridComponent gridLambda = c -> {
    if (c == 'o') {
        return new GridComponent() {
            @Override
            public String getEncoding() {
                return "o";
            }
        };
    } else if (c == 'w') {
        return new GridComponent() {
            @Override
            public String getEncoding() {
                return "w";
            }
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

But this code has errors:

```
operator "==" cannot be applied to <lamba parameter>, 'char'?
```

Comment: Your lambda `c -> { ... }`  is implementing the functional interface `GridComponent`. i.e. `c -> { ... }` is an implementation of `String getEncoding()`. So it should take nothing and return a string. The compiler is complaining that it doesn't know what `c` is. Your actual outer function is more like a `Function<Character, GridComponent>`. That itself is not a GridComponent; it's something that *can give you* a GridComponent if you give it a character first.

Comment: All you need here is `c -> return c;`. Unclear why you think you need this, once it is simplified this much.

Comment: @Michael I see a lot of upvotes on your comment but I am not sure what you mean, how do I check weather it is an 'o' or a 'w' ?

Comment: @user207421 That's invalid syntax FYI. Either `c -> { return c; }` or (preferably) `c -> c` or  `Function.identity()`

Comment: @Michael Yes indeed.

Comment: @Michael Hi Michael, but how do I check weather it is 'o' or 'w', my return is "o" and "w"

Comment: @user207421 I am taking char but returning string? How can I solve this ?

Comment: I don't understand the follow-up question, sorry. I re-read my initial explanation and I don't currently see how I can improve on it. Suffices to say `c -> {...}` cannot be assigned to GridComponent, because `c -> {}` takes 1 argument and GridComponent's single abstract method (getEncoding) takes none.

Comment: What I think you mean here is `GridComponent getGridComponent(char c) { if (c == 'o' || c == 'w') return () -> String.valueOf(c); else return null; }`. Putting the test inside the lambda just defers the inevitable: there is no benefit.

Comment: @user207421 but is that still a lambda function or is it just a function now?

Comment: It is a function that returns a lambda. But I haven't compiled it ...

Comment: @Michael, Hi Michael I have added additional information as to what I want to achieve, maybe I was describing what I wanted incorrectly, I think it is what you said? Can you please confirm?

Comment: @user207421 I have added some more information about what I want. But I dont think it was what you described

Comment: I don't see anything in your edit that either invokes your original code or invalidates my suggestion. "I want to create a lambda function that will create the GridComponent object that returns the encoding": no, I don't think you do. You want to create a function that returns a `GridComponent` lambda that returns the encoding. Which I provided. You're using a lambda where you don't need one, and you're not using one where you do. Perhaps you want the lambda to be `() -> return "ERROR"` in the case that `c` is invalid, instead of null, but it's anybody's guess really.

Comment: It's important you realize that a lambda expression is essentially just "syntactic sugar" (i.e., shorthand) for defining an implementation of a functional interface, which an interface with a single abstract method (SAM). In this case, you're trying to implement `GridComponent` whose SAM is `getEncoding()`. That means the lambda expression will have **no parameters** and must return a `String`. But the lambda you have in the question is defining a single parameter `c` and trying to return `GridComponent`. See the problem?

Comment: Perhaps if you try to implement what you want using anonymous classes first, then you can at least get everything working like you want. Then convert the anonymous classes to lambda expressions (your IDE might provide an "action" that does such a conversion for you).

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is something like this:

```
GridComponent createGridComponent(char c) {
    if (c == 'o') {
        return () -> "o";
    } else if (c == 'w') {
        return () -> "w";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Depending on the version of Java you're using, this could be further simplified, e.g. (Java >= 12):

```
GridComponent createGridComponentEncoder(char c) {
    return switch (c) {
        case 'o' -> () -> "o";
        case 'w' -> () -> "w";
        default -> null;
    };
}
```

Comment: jon hanson, thanks for the reponse, I have added additional information about what I want to active

Comment: @SarahV.P Well that makes two people with the same suggestion. Please state clearly which of your objectives it fails to meet.